# What is the current status of consecutive days logged in using the SE (Android) app?

Tags: support, android-app, consecutive-days

I'll not have access to my PC in a few days, and since I have a 270 consecutive streak going on over at SO I was wondering the following:

Does the Android SE app qualify for consecutive access? And if so, what do I need to do to gain the consecutive access to a particular SE site?

I can see an issue with that with the app you access the whole SE platform, but not your specific sites.

I haven't been able to find any up to date FAQ, apart from meta questions of a year old, hence I'm requesting the current status.

Comment: While not direct duplicate, the answer there fits perfectly and looks like your streak won't break. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I disagree with the close: It is a topic of 1 year old, and does not really *answer* what you need to do to get the consecutive access for a site registered.

Comment: Kevin clearly says *We're now counting access to a site via the app for both "last seen" **and the "daily site access" for the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges*** which answers your "Does the Android SE app qualify for consecutive access?" question. As for what exact actions are needed guess it's a secret to prevent users from gaming the badges (by making bots) but pretty sure voting should be enough. If you still want an official answer here I'll reopen.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, I was just curious about whether opening the newsfeed was enough, or whether I need to open a question from that specific site, hence why I was asking it like this. And gaming is very easy if you just make a bot that logs in to the site every day... shouldn't have anything to do with the app

Comment: Kevin said "this basically means accessing the feed doesn't count" so this should quell your curiosity. You can also leave a comment on his answer, maybe he'll even edit it with updated information.